# How to plot a line chart which has both the start and points outside the canvas area using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am currently using chart.js **"2.9.4"** and the "react-chartjs-2 **"2.11.1"**.
My goal is to draw a line chart which has **only** two data points. Both these two data points are outside the canvas.

Here I attached a reference image.

[image]

Please help me to find a solution for this issue. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [scatter](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/charts/scatter.html) chart and define `ticks.min` and `ticks.max` options on the x-axis to limit the view. In order to see the line, you need to add `showLine: true` on the `dataset`.

> Consult the Chart.js documentation for further details about [tick configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration).

Please take a look at the runnable code snippet below and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    labels: [2018, 2024],
    datasets: [{
      data: [{ x: 2018, y: 10 }, { x: 2024, y: 0 }],
      borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
      showLine: true,
      fill: false
    }],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 2020,
          max: 2023,
          stepSize: 1
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks @uminder, This is what I am exactly looking for.